# Spock tests problem with spring-boot-starter 1.5.16.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, groovy

I upgrade my project from spring-boot-starter 1.2.3 to 1.5.16 and now I'm getting problems to launch spock tests.The error is:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on proyect: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotationAttributes(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/String;ZZ)Lorg/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationAttributes;
```

I read that maybe  is a spring-test and spring-core version but I have the same version `4.1.6.RELEASE`

Comment: I also upgrade maven-surefire-plugin to 2.22.0